# Get error response from APNS when send push notification?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, push, response

I have used this code to send push notification to iOS device. When the device token is correct it work great, I can receive notification and the response from APNS to my server is nothing. But when I change the device token to wrong token, I still receive nothing from APNS, there is no error code in reponse. I want to get error response from APNS when pushing invalid token.

```
 <?php

error_reporting(0);
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
//include "dbconn.php";
$data = array();
$json= array();
$users = array();


$deviceToken = 'gddhfkgjhkjkgkgkgkgkjk2c2967b1fbc03fbebccb4109bbc509493938dcf70c3e674b949e1f81475ea742';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'testpush1234';


// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

$token = $deviceToken;

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
# Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                           $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);


 if (!$fp){
    echo "Error fp: ".$err;
    exit;
}

echo "\n".'Connected to APNS Push Notification' . PHP_EOL;

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default'
                     );

$payload = json_encode($body);
//echo "\n$payload" . PHP_EOL;

// Build the binary notification
$apple_expiry = time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60); 
$apple_identifier = 1;
$msg = pack("C", 1) . pack("N", $apple_identifier) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload; 

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

//set blocking
stream_set_blocking($fp,0);

//Check response
checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

function checkAppleErrorResponse($fp) {

    $apple_error_response = fread($fp, 6); //byte1=always 8, byte2=StatusCode, bytes3,4,5,6=identifier(rowID). Should return nothing if OK.
    //NOTE: Make sure you set stream_set_blocking($fp, 0) or else fread will pause your script and wait forever when there is no response to be sent.

    echo 'apple_error_response ' . $apple_error_response;

    if ($apple_error_response) {

        $error_response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $apple_error_response); //unpack the error response (first byte 'command" should always be 8)

        echo "==============";
        echo $error_response;
        echo "==============";

        if ($error_response['status_code'] == '0') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '0-No errors encountered';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '1') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '1-Processing error';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '2') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '2-Missing device token';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '3') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '3-Missing topic';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '4') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '4-Missing payload';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '5') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '5-Invalid token size';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '6') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '6-Invalid topic size';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '7') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '7-Invalid payload size';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '8') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '8-Invalid token';

        } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '255') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '255-None (unknown)';

        } else {
            $error_response['status_code'] = $error_response['status_code'].'-Not listed';

        }

        echo '<br><b>+ + + + + + ERROR</b> Response Command:<b>' . $error_response['command'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Identifier:<b>' . $error_response['identifier'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status:<b>' . $error_response['status_code'] . '</b><br>';
        echo 'Identifier is the rowID (index) in the database that caused the problem, and Apple will disconnect you from server. To continue sending Push Notifications, just start at the next rowID after this Identifier.<br>';

        return true;
    }

    echo "\nPush respnse OK" . PHP_EOL;
    return false;
}
```

?>